# trying to get rid of strange reflections

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

i've a pretty simple scene since i'm a beginner doing backroom hallways with simple texture and no special effects. first half of my render looked decent without those strange reflections at the walls.

that wall to the right has very strange reflections/things going on.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6UXWkQO7Co

no matter how much light i use (from 30 to 3 sources, from 1900 strength to 500k), how many samples (up to 400-500), or resolution (up to 1600x1200).
tried different light max bounces settings (the ones in my screenshot are my defaults which worked prefect till this section. the walls never did this till that hallway.

there are no doubles, normals are all good and i'm totally out of ideas. it's now day3 rendering to find a solution.

[image: render settings]

here is the blend file https://workupload.com/file/GyVWgdjNLGk